# MVC4 Ajax Post Action Parameter Null

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've a controller with post action. Using javascript ajax to post the data, the action parameter is always null. Any suggestion ?

**Routing**

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        null,
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
    );
```

**Ajax**

```
public register(data: any): bool {
    var url = this.baseUrl + "Account/Register/";
    var xhr: JQueryXHR = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: { id: 0, "Username": "myUser", "Password" : "myPass" },
        async: false,
        cache: false,
    });
    return (xhr.status == 200);
}
```

**Action**

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Mvc.ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public void Register(UserLogin login)
```

**UserLogin**

```
public class UserLogin
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 data: JSON.stringify({ login : { id: 0, "Username": "myUser", "Password" : "myPass" }}),
```

Comment: JSON.stringify dit it. Do not put it iniside object again as single parameter.

Comment: you mean : `data: JSON.stringify({ id: 0, "Username": "myUser", "Password" : "myPass" }),` @Abc . This works for web api, but if you work with mvc, it should be like my answer

Comment: maybe you take a look at this ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500003/mvc4-action-post-parameters-error-500-internal-server-error