# MVC4 Action Post Parameters Error 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've a controller with a post action (multiple parameters). Using javascript ajax to post the data, i got a `500 Internal Server Error`. Any suggestion ?

**Routing**

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        null,
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
    );
```

**Ajax**

```
public register(data: any): bool {
    var url = this.baseUrl + "Account/Register/";
    var xhr: JQueryXHR = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({
                 login: ({ Id: 0, "Username": "myUser", "Password": "myPass" }),
                 company: ({ Id: 0, "Name": "myCompany" })
              }),
        async: false,
        cache: false,
    });
    return (xhr.status == 200);
}
```

**Action**

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Mvc.ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public void Register(UserLogin login, Company company)
```

**UserLogin**

```
public class UserLogin
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

**Company**

```
public class Company
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Comment: First suggestion would be to check the debugger for more information than a 500 error. Second, I don't think you want to pass the data as stringified JSON. This answer has more information about passing JSON with an XHR: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446024/post-json-with-mvc-4-api-controler

Comment: already tried without stringify. it should work this way... maybe something with the route config ?

Comment: @Abc: check my updated answer regarding `ValidateAntiForgeryToken`, hope it helps

Comment: i will, thanks for your hint

Answer (score 2):

I have not seen a syntax to declare javascript object like this. Maybe this could be the problem. Try:

```
data: JSON.stringify({
                     login: { UserId : 0, Username: "myUser", Password: "myPass" },
                     company: { CompanyId : 0, Name: "myCompany" }
                  })
```

Remove your `(` and `)`

Another problem could be because of `ValidateAntiForgeryToken`. This filter is to prevent CSRF, you have to send your **Request Verification Token** to the server. Try removing this filter first to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
  public register(data: any): bool {
        var url = this.baseUrl + "Account/Register/";
        var xhr: JQueryXHR = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                     login: ({ UserId : 0, Username: "myUser", Password: "myPass" }),
                     company: ({ CompanyId : 0, Name: "myCompany" })
                  }),
            async: false,
            cache: false,
        });
        return (xhr.status == 200);
    }
```

UserLogin

```
public class UserLogin
{
    public int UserId {get; set;}
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Company

```
public class Company
{
    public int CompanyId {get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why the id should change something ? But appreciate your answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

According to this link [Posting parameters](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding.aspx#10302750) this is not possible. You can just pass one object to the action constructor while post.